# HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/BookStore/index.html) is not available

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, deployment, jboss

I'm working with my web application and it uses JBoss 7 AS as application server. I have recently installed JBoss 7 and it starts smoothly. Now when I try to run very simple web application with just index.html under WebContent folder I get following error:

`HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/BookStore/index.html) is not available`

I know it means that JBoss server can't find that location but what can go so wrong when I don't see any errors in console.

Here's my **web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>BookStore</display-name>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And **index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What I can do in this case? I'm using Eclipse Indigo and to clarify I haven't deployed the .war file of the project before I got **HTTP Status 404 error**. However when I tried to deploy that specific .war file by creating file called BookStore.war.dodeploy **JBOSS_PATH/Standalone/Deployments** I got deployment failed error and the root cause of the error was this:

```
16:06:02,958 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl] (MSC service     thread 1-4) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Amir\workspace\BookStoreDB;create=true
16:06:02,966 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
16:06:02,974 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000430: The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead
16:06:02,980 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
16:06:02,986 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory
16:06:02,991 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
16:06:03,056 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
16:06:03,554 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
16:06:03,555 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
16:06:03,555 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000319: Could not get database metadata: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Amir\workspace\BookStoreDB;create=true
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:194) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
```

Regarding that above error I'm using Embdedded Derby and I have checked and made sure that it has Embedded Derby driver in libraries/jars. I'm also using Hibernate to establish connection. What's also funny is that when I run JUnit tests where I save some data to database it works but for some reason I just don't get why it says in the above error 
`Could not obtain connection to query metadata : No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Amir\workspace\BookStoreDB;create=true`.

Comment: copy the derby driver into server shared library, restart the server and have a try

Comment: Why is your <url-pattern> for Faces Servlet commented out?

Comment: ->mrangry777: it's not actually commented out, it is wrongly convereted here in this site.

Comment: ->user2511414: I have actually added Derby 10.10. library in Classpath and made sure that it contains the exact same driver_class of Hibernate persistence unit. But I'm going to give a try to put it in JBoss Runtime library. I don't know does it make sense at all :)

Comment: ->user2511414: Where is server shared library located? Do you mean JBoss 7.1 Runtime library with this server shared library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research in depth I found out that JBoss AS7 doesn't actually support YET MyFaces. One of JBoss developers answered to that question following:

> > Hello JBoss Team,
>
> I would like to know if i can use MyFaces instead of Mojarra as jsf
>   implementation. Sorry if this is not the place to ask this question.
>
> Thanks
>
> Rafael Castro
>
> **For AS7, we don't currently have any way to let you use MyFaces.  It's
>   on the todo list, but it's not scheduled for a release yet.
>
> Stan**

Here's the URL for that disucssion [Use MyFaces instead of Mojarra with JBoss AS7](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-as7-dev/2011-July/003086.html).

So it seems that you have to use previous versions of JBoss, for example JBoss 6. Hope this helps.